# Explicitly calling onrender event of TextInputCell on FieldUpdater Event

Tags: gwt, datagrid, render

I am using `DataGrid` in a `GWT`. One of the column is `TextIntputCell`. I want to place one tooltip on the same cell to show the updated value at each `FieldUpdter` Event.

Following is the code.

```
TextInputCell commentCell= new TextInputCell();{
@Override
public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context,                                 String value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
String imagePath = GWT.getModuleBaseURL()                           + "/images/about.png";
sb.appendHtmlConstant("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
sb.appendHtmlConstant("<img src = '" + imagePath + "'height = '20px' width = '20px'  title='"+value+"'/>");
}
};
commentColumn = new Column<RegisteredClasses, String>(commentCell) {
@Override
public String getValue(RegisteredClasses object) {
return "";
}
};
FieldUpdater<RegisteredClasses, String> commentUpdater = new FieldUpdater<RegisteredClasses, String>() {
@Override
public void update(int index, RegisteredClasses object, String value) {
if(value != null ){
object.setCommentsByContractor(value);
}
}
};
commentColumn.setFieldUpdater(commentUpdater);
table.addColumn(commentColumn, localizableResource.onAcceptanceComment());
table.setColumnWidth(commentColumn, "280px");
```

This is not working as the render event is called once only. Is there any way to call it explicitly.